# Jquery add item in @Model that I got from HTML inputfield

Tags: c#, jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have the following Jquery function :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".UrlButton").click(function () {
            alert('button clicked');            
            var item = $(".UrlField").val();
            @Model.Urls.Add(item);           
        });
    });
```

with the following button

```
        <input type="text" class="UrlField" />
        <button type="button" class="UrlButton">+</button>
```

I'm trying to add an item to the @Model.Urls, which is just a string.

But with the above example i cant  add item because  'it does not excist in the current context'.

How can I add something to my model by using Jquery and getting the item from a HTML-inputfield?

Thanks!

Comment: The var 'item' can't be added to Model.Urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The `Model` exists at a different time than the javascript environment will because they are in different parts of the http pipeline

HTTP Pipeline for mvc is basically as follows

1. global asax receives a request
2. global asax routes the request to a controller
3. controller builds data for the response
4. the view takes any data populated from the controller and streams the response (this is where the exception for `Model.Urls.Add(item)` is, because `item` does not exist server side)

The response consists essentially of a `.html` file once streamed. That is the end of the server's involvement, and that is the end of the object lifetime of `Model`.

From that point forward, the browser begins rendering the response. The rendering engine parses the html, including its scrips styles and layout, and builds the Document Object Model.

At this point, the DOM contains the element you are assigning an event handler to. This is now very far from the original point where `Model`'s lifetime was.

In order to still have access to data from `Model`, that data should be serialized to JSON and then stored in the client environment for use.

In order to modify data contained in the `Model`, an ajax call must be made.

Comment: So this means I'll have to find another way I guess... =S